# Why are there a lot of "<!--!-->" in the developer tools to see between my html code in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

Why are there a lot of signs in the developer tools to see between my html code in Blazor?

And how can i get rid of it ?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21526 : Read this

Comment: [Polite] Suggest one of you drops that in as the answer and then ticks if off.

Comment: You can hide them in Chromium browsers - in settings you can choose to hide HTML comments, but they are an integral part of Blazor, so you can't remove them.

Answer (score 0):

As @yasseros suggested:
[github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21526](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21526)

> The reason is because the internal JS algorithm uses them to map the
> component structure from the Blazor representation to the one in the
> page.
>
> Comments are needed to avoid introducing artificial elements to
> delimit the start and end of components.
>
> One example of this is if you have something like
>
> 1   2   3
>  child.razor
>
> Title @ChildContent
>
> Body @ChildContent The renderer
> needs to know where each child.razor starts and ends.